# How can I force function parameters onto new lines?

Tags: kotlinpoet

I want all function parameters to be generated on a new line, like so:

```
fun test(
    a: Int,
    b: Int,
    c: Int
)
```

How can I do this? At the moment the parameter lists wrap arbitrarily. I have an unknown number of function parameters to generate.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, if the function has more than 2 parameters, each parameter will appear on a new line, otherwise the function signature will be printed on a single line. We don't provide APIs for modifying this behavior.